# Python 3 & GTK3: crossplatform tray icon

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

It's [possible](https://github.com/afiskon/py-gtk-example/blob/master/gtk-example.py) to create a tray icon with a menu using AppIndicator3. But this solution is not portable. For instance [it doesn't work on FreeBSD](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2016-June/272287.html) since there is no libappindicator3 on this system. I suspect that such code doesn't work on Windows and MacOS either.

How to do the same without AppIndicator3 so code would work on all (or almost all) systems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured it out. The idea is to fallback to Gtk.StatusIcon if AppIndicator3 is unavailable:

```
class TrayIcon:

    def __init__(self, appid, icon, menu):
        self.menu = menu

        APPIND_SUPPORT = 1
        try:
            from gi.repository import AppIndicator3
        except:
            APPIND_SUPPORT = 0

        if APPIND_SUPPORT == 1:
            self.ind = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new(
                appid, icon, AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS)
            self.ind.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
            self.ind.set_menu(self.menu)
        else:
            self.ind = Gtk.StatusIcon()
            self.ind.set_from_file(icon)
            self.ind.connect('popup-menu', self.onPopupMenu)

    def onPopupMenu(self, icon, button, time):
        self.menu.popup(None, None, Gtk.StatusIcon.position_menu, icon, button, time)
```

Works on Linux + Unity, Linux + Xfce, FreeBSD + i3.

See also:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1923373#post11902222
- https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing-gtk/blob/master/syncthing_gtk/statusicon.py
- https://github.com/afiskon/py-gtk-example